# Does a hat designed for RPi 2 B still work on Rpi4 (GPIO compatbility)?

Tags: gpio, pi-2, pi-4, hat

I'm now continuing the design of a PCB (Pi Hat) that I started with a RPi 2 Model B.

Will a RPi4 accept this hat?

**TL;DR: Does a RPi4 accept a Pi Hat designed for RPi 2 B? Or is there a break in the compatibility?**

Answer (score 4):

The official design specification for a Raspberry Pi HAT hasn't changed since 2014 when the current form-factor was launched with the RPiB+. There's no hardware reason why a HAT for a RPi2B won't run on a RPi4B.

The thing that may need to change is the software driver as 32-bit Buster is a bit different to Jessie. The RPF/RP(T)Ltd. folks have just launched a 64-bit kernel for end-user testing.